# Need advice on MongoDB schema for multiple types of items in a single collection

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am designing an "Itinerary Planner" application. The concept is pretty simple, each itinerary will have three types of items:

1. transportation: Has fields like `startDate`, `endDate`, `provider`, `source`, `destination`.
2. accommodation: Has fields like `startDate`, `endDate`, `provider`, `location`.
3. activity: Has fields like `startDate`, `endDate`, `name`, `location`.

As you might have noticed, these items have similar but not the exact same fields always. I ended up with the following schema:

```js
const transportationSchema = new Schema({
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  provider: String,
  mode: String,
  source: String,
  destination: String,
});

const accommodationSchema = new Schema({
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  provider: String,
  location: String,
});

const activitySchema = new Schema({
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  name: String,
  location: String,
});

const itinerarySchema = new Schema({
  tripId: { type: ObjectId, ref: "trip" },
  type: String,
  transportation: transportationSchema,
  accommodation: accommodationSchema,
  activity: activitySchema,
});

const ItineraryModel = mongoose.model("itinerary", itinerarySchema);
```

Where the itinerary elements can be pulled by giving the `tripId`. But this results in the API input validations way difficult than they should be. For instance, if the `type` field in API is `transportation`, I would need to manually check for the entries being present inside it. I am not saying other input validations are easy, but they are less confusing to look at if everything was a flat structure.

Is there an industry standard for these scenarios? I also don't want to make the querying complex by creating a collection for each of these itinerary types. What should I do and how should I structure the DB?

Comment: When considering the preferred schema we look to optimize.  Otherwise a flat structure is sufficient.  To optimize, we must look at data access patterns.  Of these patterns, you may have 1 that is the most common, considered the primary data access pattern.  It is this data access usage that should be optimized.  On your specific schema, I would ask - can I have more than 1 activity, or more than one transportation in a single itinerary model?

Comment: @barrypicker It is not possible to have more than 1 transportation. Similarly, accommodation and activity. Each document is a single card in the UI. What do you suggest here?

Answer (score 0):

1:1 relationship is easy to model and code. In your case every key is having 1:1 relationship. This is the present status.

Let us think about a case you would need to develop a function which takes in the keys in transportationSchema. How do you design the interface of this function ? Will it be a function which accepts 2 dates and 4 string args ? if so, how will you pass the actual values into the same function ? Again, 2 date values and 4 string values. What will be the advantage you may get if you design a function which accepts an object instead ? Will the number of formal arguments be reduced to just one ? Will the number of actual arguments be reduced to just one ? What about the consequences if you decide later to pass a numeric value in addition to the existing 6 six values ? How will you incorporate this change ?

In short, subdocuments are used to structure your data model. This will lead to better mental model, easy coding and maintenance. It is up to you to take the call whether you take a step in this regard either today or tomorrow, still it will become inevitable as you go forward.

Thanks
WeDoTheBest4You.